# ToList() in LINQ -c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a LINQ query which combines two lists (`supplier` and `customers`) based on their country.

The supplier and customer classes created are given below. Apart from that I have created one more class suppliercustomer in order to add the result to a new list.

```
public class Supplier
{
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public Order[] Orders { get; set; }
}

public class SupplierCustomer
{
    public SupplierCustomer()
    {
    }

    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public Order[] Orders { get; set; }
}

//returns empty result    

List<Customer> customers = GetCustomerList();
List<Supplier> suppliers = GetSupplierList();

List<SupplierCustomer> lt =
  (from sup in suppliers
   join cust in customers on sup.Country equals cust.Country
   select new SupplierCustomer()).ToList<SupplierCustomer>();

//working query
var custSupJoin =
  from sup in suppliers
  join cust in customers on sup.Country equals cust.Country
  select new { Country = sup.Country, SupplierName = sup.SupplierName, CustomerName = cust.CompanyName };
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in custSupJoin)
{
    output = output + "\n " + i + "." + "Country=" + item.Country.ToString() + ", Supplier = ," + " Customer =" + item.SupplierName.ToString() + item.CustomerName + "\n";
    i++;
}
```

[image]
Why is the first query not working? I need to convert the result to a new list in a single query.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? The two queries should return an identical number of rows.

Comment: Im getting empty result for the first query.

Comment: The fact that your `SupplierCustomer` constructor doesn't *do* anything really doesn't help... but I'd expect you to have the same number of results. Please provide a [mcve] - which will mean removing irrelevant properties from `Supplier` and `Customer` too.

Comment: Shouldn't your `SupplierCustomer` constructor also take a `Customer`?

Comment: Don't you need to set values in `SupplierCustomer` constructor?

Comment: Lazy loading perhaps?

Comment: Judging by your screenshot, your query *isn't* returning an empty result - it's returning a list with the right number of results, *each of which* is empty, because you didn't do anything in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have simpified your question and provided answer in one

#### Supplier Class

```
class Supplier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; } // what you're using to join to customer
    // the rest of your properties
}
```

#### Customer Class

```
class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }  // what you're using to join to supplier
    // the rest of your properties
}
```

#### SupplierCustomer Class

> This is all you need to do for your SupplierCustomer class, in fact this will greatly improve your code maintainability, as it will always map perfectly to your above types.

```
class SupplierCustomer
{
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

## Sample & Solution

```
void Main()
{
    var suppliers = new List<Supplier>()
    {
        new Supplier() { Id = 1, Country = "USA" },
        new Supplier() { Id = 2, Country = "Japan" },
    };

    var customers = new List<Customer>()
    {
        new Customer() { Id = 10, Country = "USA" },
        new Customer() { Id = 11, Country = "USA" },
        new Customer() { Id = 20, Country = "Japan" },
        new Customer() { Id = 21, Country = "Japan" },
    };


    // Solution: 
    // Lambda-styled LINQ query to merge the two types

    List<SupplierCustomer> supplierCustomers = suppliers.Join(
        customers,
        supplier => supplier.Country, // primary key
        customer => customer.Country, // foreign key
        (supplier, customer) => new SupplierCustomer
        {
            Supplier = supplier,
            Customer = customer
        }).ToList();

    // Read up about Enumerations and the issues with doing a ToList() early.
    // You should avoid doing this heavy call in production and
    // try and optimize the result first!
}
```

#### Alternative style query

The same as the above, but in your requested format.

```
List<SupplierCustomer> query = (
    from customer in customers
    join supplier in suppliers on customer.Country equals supplier.Country
    select new SupplierCustomer
    {
      Supplier = supplier,
      Customer = customer
    })
    .ToList();
```

---

The above queries will result in a List of

```
// USA
SupplierCustomer[0] = Supplier { Id = 1, Country = "USA" }
                      Customer { Id = 10, Country = "USA" }
SupplierCustomer[1] = Supplier { Id = 1, Country = "USA" }
                      Customer { Id = 11, Country = "USA" }
// Japan
SupplierCustomer[2] = Supplier { Id = 2, Country = "Japan" }
                      Customer { Id = 20, Country = "Japan" }
SupplierCustomer[3] = Supplier { Id = 2, Country = "Japan" }
                      Customer { Id = 21, Country = "Japan" }
```

Note: You can access the `Supplier` type and `Customer` type within the **merged** `SupplierCustomer` type like so:

```
SupplyCustomer supplierCustomer = new SupplyCustomer();
Customer customer = supplierCustomer.Customer;
Supplier supplier = supplierCustomer.Supplier;
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a detailed answer to my question. could you please help me to find what exactly makes my query not working? and how I can correct it?

Comment: @user1357872  - I did... Simply your `SupplierCustomer` class, to what I made. The rest of the code will function exactly as you want.

Comment: Thank you. Im trying the same with LINQ query.   List<SupplierCustomer> lt =
              from sup in suppliers
               join cust in customers on sup.Country equals cust.Country
               select (supplier, customer) => new SupplierCustomer
         {
             Supplier = supplier,
             Customer = customer
         }; There are some syntax error.

Comment: @user1357872 just (1) copy my `SupplierCustomer` Class. (2) copy and paste my query, (don't make edits to it)..

Comment: But I dont want Lambda expression. I need the same as LINQ query.

Comment: @user1357872 No, you don't need the other style of query. Use his code. Same result either way.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, We are following LINQ queries in our application and looking for a solution in that way.

Comment: @user1357872 - I have provided the alternative below it... :)

Comment: @user1357872 Well, in that case just use the correct syntax and you'll be fine.

Comment: @user1357872 -- now you don't have to go down voting to hate! haha seriously. I did you a solid and added the alternative LINQ query.

Comment: @EdPlunkett. That's why im here.